# Problema con el código que me permite utilizar un objeto en más de una escena

Tags: c#, unity3d

Buenas tardes. Estoy desarrollando un juego que consiste en distintas escenas, y cada escena es un juego que se utilizará para rehabilitación. Para realizar el juego estoy utilizando un dispositivo llamado `"MyoArmband"` el cual trae consigo una serie de clases en c# para su utilización en Unity.

Mi problema comienza al tener el objeto que hace referencia al dispositivo en todas las escenas, ya que el usuario deberá pasar a las demás escenas utilizándolo. En el siguiente trozo de código es donde se produce la destrucción del objeto del dispositivo, y su instancia a continuación para que cuando pase a la siguiente escena, éste objeto no esté duplicado.

```
 void Awake (){


if (_instance != null){

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Can only have one ThalmicHub",
                                    "Your scene contains more than one   ThalmicHub. Remove all but one ThalmicHub.",
                                    "OK");
#endif

            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            return;
            _instance = this;

        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }

        // Do not destroy this game object. This will ensure that it remains active even when
        // switching scenes.
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
```

Cuando hago el Debug, me sale que la línea `"_instance = this"` es código inaccesible y es por ello que aunque pase a la siguiente escena, el objeto no se ejecuta.

Comment: Bienvenido! Para que el código se pueda visualizar correctamente, debe tener 4 espacios al inicio de cada línea. Esto se logra automáticamente haciendo click en el botón `{  }`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: He probado con poner esa línea debajo de "_instance = this" pero igualmente tampoco me mantiene el objeto en la siguiente escena...

Comment: ¿Probaste eliminar la línea con `return;`?

Comment: Sí, la tengo ahí comentada, pero nada... He probado también con este código que encontré en un tutorial, pero igualmente tampoco me     funciona  
     void Awake(){
 
  if (estadoMyo == null) {
   estadoMyo = this;
   DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
  
  } else if (estadoMyo != this) {
   Destroy (gameObject);  
  }
     }

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Para que tu código funcione, probablemente tengas que usa un patrón llamado **Singleton**, ya que al parecer esa es la función de tu variable **_instance**.

[Singleton en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton)

El error "este código es inaccesible" se produce porque el programa no llega a ejecutar la instrucción `"_instance = this"` debido al return.

```cs
public class LoadMyo : MonoBehaviour {
    public ThalmicMyo _instance;

    void Awake (){
         if (_instance == null){
             // inicializar myo
             _instance = new ThalmicMyo ();
         }

         // no destruir este objeto
         DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }
}
```

El código de arriba debería mantener más o menos la idea de lo que quieres hacer, pero he tenido que deducir algunas cosas, por lo que podría no funcionar. Deduzco que tu objeto Myo se guarda en `_instance` porque el if muestra un mensaje de que debe haber una sola instancia.

Aun así tu pregunta está un poco incompleta.

Para obtener este objeto desde otro en una escena nueva puedes usar una instrucción del tipo

```cs
ThalmicMyo myo = GameObject.Find("LoadMyo").GetComponent<ThalmicMyo>();
```

Como se muestra en el link [GameObject.Find()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)